# Submit value to Rails Model

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, models

if i have this as my form

```
<%= form_for @rating, :id =>"ratingForm" do |f| %>
<%= f.hidden_field :ratings, :value => '' %>
<%= f.hidden_field :user_id, :value => current_user.id %>
<%= f.hidden_field :recipe_id, :value => @recipe.id %>
<div class="rateit" id="rateit10">
</div>
<%= f.submit "Submit" %>
<% end %>
```

How do i pass the value of the content within this div

```
<div class="rateit" id="rateit10">
</div>
```

if i use this jquery I can get the value of rateit10

```
$("#rateit10").bind('rated', function() { 
 $(this).rateit('value');
  });
```

The value derives from clicking upon a set of stars, im trying to implement a rating system in rails using the Rateit plugin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will pass a hash to your controller method:

```
   function pass_to_controller(){
    var rate_value = $("#ratings").value();
    var user_id = $("#user_id").value();  /*you already have access to this through current_user.id */
    var recipe_id = $("#recipe_id").value();

    $.ajax({
        type: "Get",
        url: "path_to_your_controller_action_here",
        timeout: 5000,
        data: {rating : rate_value, user : user_id, recipe : recipe_id }
    }).done(function(response){//do your response here});
}
```

You can't directly pass to the model - that circumvents the whole thought process behind MVC. So the best way to do it is to use `ajax`, pass it to your controller method, then if you need to do something in your database call your model method.

The advantage of using `ajax` like this is that it won't reload your page when someone rates something.

Comment: so i no longer need the hidden_field :ratings  within my form?

Comment: if you were to use `ajax`? Nope, because you wouldn't need to submit the whole form, just to update one value in your database.

Comment: ok, so what if there where more data to submit, say another 2 hidden fields?

Comment: Same thing `var val1, val2 = your_hidden_fields` then add them to the data hash `data: {value : rate_value, value1: val1, val2: val2} @Richlewis

Comment: I have updated question with my entire form, would you be able to provide an example please

Comment: and will i have to bind to the form to get the other hidden fields values?

Comment: thanks so much, big help, last question, the path to my controller, is it like /controller/action?

Comment: @Richlewis yes so this will reflect the rout that's generated from your routs file, so if your controller was `ratings` and your action was `def update_ratings` then the rout would most likely be `/ratings/update_ratings`

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way is to trigger an update of your hidden field when the user click on a star, rather than read the value of the stars when the form is submitted.

I should add a onnclick event on the stars to update the hidden field. To do this, add an ID to your hidden field with :id => "my_hidden_field" to name it.

Then, trigger a javascript function when the user click on a star :

```
$("#second_star").click(function() {
  $("my_hidden_field").value = 2;
});
```

Comment: Yes, I would put an id on each star and for each, bind the correct action to fill the hidden field.

Answer (score 0):

**To show text inside div using javascript:**

```
divObj = document.getElementById("rateit10");
            if ( divObj ){
                if ( divObj.textContent ){ //FF
                    alert ( divObj.textContent );
                }else{  //IE            
                    alert ( divObj.innerText );  //alert ( divObj.innerHTML );
                } 
            }
```

**To show innerdiv inside div using javascript:**

```
myDivObj = document.getElementById("rateit10");
if ( myDivObj ) {
   alert ( myDivObj.innerHTML ); 
}else{
   alert ( "Text Found" );
}
```

**To show text inside div using jquery**

```
$(function(){
       var txt = $('#rateit10').text();
       alert(txt);
    };
```